# PHP Single line array shuffle is not working

Tags: php, arrays, random, echo, shuffle

Very simple but I was wondering why this is not working.

I'm trying shuffle an array and output the results (in a single line structure)

this is my code :

```
echo shuffle(array("A","B","C"))[0];
```

Small tweak needed here ;)

Comment: what error you get??

Comment: Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference...

Comment: Yeah shuffle uses a reference so your array must be a variable.

Comment: No single line trick solution ?

Comment: Nope shuffle also doesnt return the array... it return `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic logic is a little bit wrong. You're interested in only one value, I assume? To solve it with that logic in mind, you can do it like this:

```
echo array_rand(array_flip(['A', 'B', 'C']));
```

Comment: `array_rand()` returns only the key, not the value

Comment: Working! Perfect bro!!! (need to wait to vote up + accept [Vote Up requires 15 reputation]... sry) :)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
   $arr = array("A","B","C");
   shuffle($arr);
   echo $arr[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is not the best solution for you, but it works!

```
print_r( ( $b=array('A', 'B', 'C') ) && shuffle($b) ? next($b) : null );
```

How this works:

- Assign the array to the variable `$b`
- Shuffle the variable `$b`

  - If the `shuffle()` succeeded:

    - return the next element in the array
  - If the `shuffle()` failed:

    - return `null`

---

Some might think: "Why didn't he used the `current()` function?"

Well, it seems that the function `shuffle` simply changes the order of the keys, but the pointer is always pointing to the same element. This means that `current()` will always return `'A'`.

Apparently, this behaviour changed on PHP 5.4 to set the pointer to the first element.

Comment: Nice bro! I have also tried with current() and IT DOES WORKS ! :-)

Comment: @Steven It wasn't working with me and it was always returning `'A'`. Maybe the behaviour changed on PHP 5.4 and up. I tested on PHP 5.3 and the `current()` function had the behaviour I've described.

Comment: Great man! I'm using PHP Version 5.4.4! Working perfectly! :-) Great Answer ! Thanks !

Comment: @Steven You are wellcome. This is a good usage of implicit boolean conversion. And it's nice to know I wasn't wrong about the PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS SIMPLE FUNCTION**

```
$my_array = array("A","B","C","D","E");
shuffle($my_array);
print_r($my_array);
```

Comment: I know that one bro... I was asking about single line solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass the array in a seperate variable. Also, shuffle() itself just returns a boolean value, so you need to return an array element instead of the output of the function.

```
$ar = array("A","B","C");
shuffle($ar);
echo $ar[0];
```

Comment: I know that one bro... I was asking about single line solution... Maybe with a callback ? :)